# Making 2nd level ul 100% height of the first ul instead of the parent li

Tags: html, css

I have this menu http://codepen.io/alexandernst/pen/oxpGYQ (tried to insert it here but SO's result viewer is breaking the demo...) and I want to make the second and third level `ul` elements the same height as the first level `ul` and also start at the same position (which would be `top: 0` is this concrete demo) as the first ul element.

So, said with other words, I want all `ul` elements to start at the tom of the `row` div and have 100% height.

Note that I don't know how many `li` elements I'll have, so I can't hardcode `top` values for each `ul` element in order to adjust it's `top` position.

I'd like to avoid having to use javascript, but if there is no other way I could accept an answer with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving position `static` to the `li` elements. Then when setting `height: 100%` to the `ul` element it be will relative to the parent `ul` instead of the parent `li`. So long as the `ul` element has position set to `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

**Add this CSS**

```
#cssmenu ul li {
  position: static !important;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1b9bff;
}
```

Here is the Codepen solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzZXxv

Comment: This is perfect! Just one small detail. The 3rd `ul` has maybe 1 or 2px less height than the 2nd. Any idea why could that be?

Comment: Ah, it was because of the border. I think I got it :)